# Apple Silicon, Monterey - Window title bar persists on full-screen when switching focus back and forth

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

When I have a window on full-screen, if I move the cursor up to reveal the title bar (where the close, minimize buttons are), then switch to another window and back again, the title bar stays visible. It doesn't disappear unless I move the cursor over it, then away.

It's easier to explain with a [screen recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AIlqdTQxxQ).

This doesn't happen if I override the app settings (via "get info") and check "Scale to fit below builtin camera".

Comment: It could look like a bug in Google Chrome. Does it happen with other applications, or only Google Chrome?

Comment: It happens everywhere, though on Chrome the title bar is on the same layer as the application, so it pushes everything down, as you can see in the video. In other apps the title bar just overlays the application content, which is less disrupting.